# How can I setup Jmeter distributed configuration in cloud(AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I am currently running JMeter in 5 local VMs in which one acts as master and 4 as slaves. I want to move them to amazon servers. Can anyone suggest step by step configuration methods. Searched internet and couldn't find a documentation with full clarity. Or can anyone share a good documentation link on this?
jmeter version: 3.2

My requirements are:

1. 1 master and 4 slaves.
2. the master should have Linux GUI because I need JMETER GUI to run the test, since we are analyzing real time running data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, double check you looked for instructions well enough, i.e. there is [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) project which automates the process of installation and configuration of JMeter remote engines.

---

In general, the process doesn't differ from configuring JMeter in distributed mode locally, Amazon EC2 instances are basically the same machines as local ones and require the same configuration steps. Just make sure to open the following ports:

- `1099`
- the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
- the ports you define as `client.rmi.localport`

It has to be done both in [Linux Firewall](https://opensource.com/article/18/9/linux-iptables-firewalld) and [AWS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Check out the following material:

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)
- [Load Testing with Jmeter and Amazon EC2](https://medium.com/@alttaf/load-testing-with-jmeter-and-amazon-ec2-e143a7350596)